# kubernetes use subpath and hostPath DirectoryOrCreate,but can not create dir

Tags: kubernetes

this my volume config,I want to use the following configuration to create this directory when the hostpath does not exist, but the corresponding /root/host directory cannot be created after adding a subpath

```
containers:
- image: 10.10.0.253/public/nginx:1.19.1-alpine
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  name: nginx
  resources: {}
  terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
  terminationMessagePolicy: File
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /data
    name: nginx-hostpath
    subPath: subtest
dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
restartPolicy: Always
schedulerName: default-scheduler
securityContext: {}
shareProcessNamespace: false
terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
volumes:
- hostPath:
    path: /root/host
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
  name: nginx-hostpath
```

Comment: I would almost always avoid a `hostPath` volume.  Imagine you have 3 replicas of this pod, and they get scheduled on different nodes; you wouldn't typically want the replicas to serve different content depending on which node they get scheduled on.

Answer (score 0):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath

As per doc, it can only refer to a subpath available inside the volume root directory. In your case, as you are creating the root directory if not already available. Subpath will not be available inside the newly created folder.

Also as per doc, this is not recommended for production.

Edit:

If you look at [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), it clearly mentions that kubelet need access to create directory at given path for volume host path. I changed the path to a location where kubelet have access and it create the volume and subpath.

Comment: My /root/host Directory itself does not exist, but why is this directory (/root/host) not created

Comment: Sorry for delay, i have updated the answer